# returning json object from controller to jsp

Tags: json, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to send all the data from the DB as a `json array` to jsp to be fetched by ajax.

EmployeeController

```
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Employee> listAllUsers() {
    return employeeService.listEmployeess();
}
```

and the jsp

```
ajaxCall = function() { 
    $.ajax({
        url : 'EmployeeController',
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        error : function(that, e) {
            alert(e);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });     
}
```

so how to make this?

Comment: What is returned when you call `employeeService.listEmployeess()`?

Comment: Use Gson library and the method `.toGson(Your_Object)` will convert your Java object into json array. Or use `jackson` library which will return your response as json array.

Answer (score 0):

By Default your REST Controller converts java objects into JSON object out-of-the Box. But you can also use `@Produces("application/json")` above the controller method.

Please try to run the ajax response data in a loop `data[i]`, if it doesn't work then use the dot invocation method to reach the data.